# How to make dynamic y position of view from storyboard using auto layout

Tags: ios, autolayout

Is it possible to set dynamic `y` position of `UiView` through storyboard using auto layout?

I have one `UIView` which I want to set the `y` position of 1/3rd of the total Screen height.

thanks in advance

Comment: just add view and give the constant on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create it like this by hooking top constraint  = bottom with multiplier of 1/3

[image]

Or top = centerY with multiplier of 2/3

[image]